# How do I create a moving average in sql that restarts from variables

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to create rolling averages for a data set like

```
data have;
  do cat1 = 1 to 10;
    do cat2 = 'A', 'B', 'C';
      do seq = 1 to 20;
        value = cat1 * 10 + seq;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

I have tried to used proc expand and it works when I manually filter a set of variables I want it to be done on. My problem is one, I cant get the variables to be organized with dates like the last table. Two, I cant get the rolling average to restart every time the variable "group" changes.

Comment: Show your actual data, not a photograph of something.  Show the code you tried, explain how it did not work.  Did you use a BY statement to run the proc by group?

Comment: See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).